# Practical difference between a singleton and an extension?

Tags: swift, singleton

I need to share the current location of the user throughout the app and originally I created a singleton for this (updated by the location manager, accessible anywhere):

```
final class CurrentLocation {

    static let shared = CurrentLocation()
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    private init() {}

}

if let currentLocation = CurrentLocation.shared.coordinates {
    //
}
```

Then I thought to extend `UIDevice` to achieve the same effect without the singleton (updated by the location manager and accessible anywhere):

```
extension UIDevice {

    static var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

}

if let currentLocation = UIDevice.coordinates {
    //
}
```

In the practical sense, is there any difference? Singletons are commonly looked down as globals in disguise but is not the extension, when used like this, the same thing?

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: You mean `difference between singleton with instance property and static property`? Because you can have `extension` of `singleton` type. It's not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the same. In terms of memory management, they are exactly the same. Because both allocate the same size that is sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) in memory. But in terms of cache and cpu, an extension is better than a singleton. Because firstly you have to access the currentLocation object to get the coordinations.